# Android app launches but couldn't load data and loading process continues forever

Tags: android, eclipse, error-log

When i click on one of the buttons after splash screen the loading goes on forever and doesn't complete for showing data on the screen. I had used various libraries for the build and there is no error because the app launches but here is the screenshot of loading screen which doesn't gives the desired output of showing loaded data.
[image: this is the screenshot]
My logcat is as follows:

```
11-15 11:37:17.509: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.u.a
11-15 11:37:17.509: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2331: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
11-15 11:37:17.509: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0082
11-15 11:37:17.519: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method gsl.a
11-15 11:37:17.519: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1728: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-15 11:37:17.519: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
11-15 11:37:17.559: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method gsj.a
11-15 11:37:17.559: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1455: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-15 11:37:17.559: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00cb
11-15 11:37:17.599: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-15 11:37:17.599: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static field 552 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-15 11:37:17.599: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
11-15 11:37:17.609: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.system.Os.symlink, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.FileApkUtils.b
11-15 11:37:17.609: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2455: Landroid/system/Os;.symlink (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x002f
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
11-15 11:37:17.609: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static field 553 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-15 11:37:17.609: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static field 552 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
11-15 11:37:17.609: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static field 551 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-15 11:37:17.609: I/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0228 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.a
11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
 11-15 11:37:17.609: I/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0228 at 0x17 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
 11-15 11:37:17.609: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
 11-15 11:37:17.609: I/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0227 at 0x26 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
 11-15 11:37:17.619: D/DynamitePackage(20419): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
 11-15 11:37:17.619: D/DynamitePackage(20419): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
 11-15 11:37:17.619: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.u.a
 11-15 11:37:17.619: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2178: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
 11-15 11:37:17.619: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0082
 11-15 11:37:17.629: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method xg.a
 11-15 11:37:17.629: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1737: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
 11-15 11:37:17.629: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
 11-15 11:37:17.629: D/dalvikvm(20419): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lhd;.common_google_play_services_unknown_issue
 11-15 11:37:17.629: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5911 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lhd;
 11-15 11:37:17.629: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0012
 11-15 11:37:17.639: D/AppStreamingHelper(20419): Creating delegate
 11-15 11:37:17.639: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(20419): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
 11-15 11:37:17.639: W/DynamiteModule(20419): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
 11-15 11:37:17.639: I/DynamiteModule(20419): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
 11-15 11:37:17.639: E/AppStreamingHelper(20419): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
        11-15 11:37:17.709: I/Ads(20419): Starting ad request.
         11-15 11:37:17.709: I/Ads(20419): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3FF33ECD82BEC89D725A83554C480B25") to get test ads on this device.
                 11-15 11:37:17.789: I/System.out(20419): http://orioninfosolutions.com/emoji/get_all_categories.php
           11-15 11:37:17.799: D/DynamitePackage(20419): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
          11-15 11:37:17.799: I/Ads(20419): Starting ad request.
                   11-15 11:37:17.799: I/Ads(20419): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3FF33ECD82BEC89D725A83554C480B25") to get test ads on this device.
 11-15 11:37:17.819: I/dalvikvm(20419): Total arena pages for JIT: 21
 11-15 11:37:18.089: D/Bible Emoji & Emoticons - UALib(20419): EventAPIClient - Sending analytic events. Request:  com.urbanairship.http.Request@22e74db0 Events: [{"data":{"time_zone":19800,"session_id":"d6f09a59-63a0-4679-8fe0-fe9f7886690a","daylight_savings":false,"notification_types":["sound","vibrate"],"carrier":"AIRTEL","lib_version":"6.4.3","connection_type":"wifi","os_version":"4.4.2","package_version":"2.4"},"type":"app_foreground","event_id":"9e49461c-2ae5-4f47-9513-a6d1df70c671","time":"1479190027.598"}]
        11-15 11:37:18.209: I/System.out(20419): =====json returned---------{"error":true,"result":"Categories not found"}
          11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
        11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
           11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):     at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:376)
      11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):  at com.bibleemoji.PopularEmojiFragment$GetCatagories.onPostExecute(PopularEmojiFragment.java:95)
      11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):  at com.bibleemoji.PopularEmojiFragment$GetCatagories.onPostExecute(PopularEmojiFragment.java:1)
       11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
       11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
       11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
 11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
      11-15 11:37:18.209: W/System.err(20419):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-15 11:37:18.209: I/System.out(20419):           http://orioninfosolutions.com/emoji/get_all_categories.php
 11-15 11:37:18.579: I/System.out(20419): =====json returned---------{"error":true,"result":"Categories not found"}
   11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
     11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at    org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:376)
     11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at com.bibleemoji.CategoriesFragment$GetCatagories.onPostExecute(CategoriesFragment.java:108)
    11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):    at com.bibleemoji.CategoriesFragment$GetCatagories.onPostExecute(CategoriesFragment.java:1)
  11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
 11-15 11:37:18.609: W/System.err(20419):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  11-15 11:37:19.099: D/Bible Emoji & Emoticons - UALib(20419): EventAPIClient - Analytic event send response: Response: ResponseBody:  ResponseHeaders: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Tue, 15 Nov 2016 06:06:39 GMT], Server=[nginx/1.6.2], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1479190039100], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], X-Android-Selected-Transport=[http/1.1], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1479190038682], X-UA-Max-Batch=[500], X-UA-Max-Total=[5120], X-UA-Max-Wait=[604800000], X-UA-Min-Batch-Interval=[60000]} ResponseMessage: OK Status: 200
11-15 11:37:19.099: I/Bible Emoji & Emoticons - UALib(20419): Analytic events uploaded successfully.
 11-15 11:37:19.139: I/dalvikvm(20419): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.m.<init>
 11-15 11:37:19.139: W/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2459: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
 11-15 11:37:19.139: D/dalvikvm(20419): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0058
 11-15 11:37:19.159: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getInstance, mInstance = com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwPasswordHandler@21d176e8
 11-15 11:37:19.159: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(27)] create-->contents = 0x638ffc70, delegate = 0x68e8b7a0
 11-15 11:37:19.159: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(35)] attaching to web_contents 
  11-15 11:37:19.159: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): setSavePassword false
  11-15 11:37:19.199: D/dalvikvm(20419): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9081K, 20% free 38124K/47252K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
11-15 11:37:19.259: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getInstance, mInstance = com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwPasswordHandler@21d176e8
 11-15 11:37:19.259: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(27)] create-->contents = 0x641f3220, delegate = 0x64ceef60
 11-15 11:37:19.259: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(35)] attaching to web_contents 
 11-15 11:37:19.259: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): setSavePassword false
 11-15 11:37:20.589: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(202)] OnPasswordFormsRendered called
 11-15 11:37:20.589: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getSavePassword false
 11-15 11:37:20.589: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:aw_password_handler_delegate_impl.cc(203)] IsSavePasswordEnabled ret is 
 11-15 11:37:20.589: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(204)] OnPasswordFormsRendered IsEnabledSavePassword is false
 11-15 11:37:20.619: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getInstance, mInstance = com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwPasswordHandler@21d176e8
 11-15 11:37:20.619: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(27)] create-->contents = 0x68e38b80, delegate = 0x68e415d0
 11-15 11:37:20.619: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(35)] attaching to web_contents 
 11-15 11:37:20.619: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): setSavePassword false
 11-15 11:37:20.639: I/Ads(20419): Ad finished loading.
 11-15 11:37:20.659: I/chromium(20419): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
 11-15 11:37:20.689: I/chromium(20419): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
 11-15 11:37:20.689: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 78
 11-15 11:37:20.689: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 144
 11-15 11:37:20.689: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 145
 11-15 11:37:20.919: I/chromium(20419): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
 11-15 11:37:20.919: I/chromium(20419): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
 11-15 11:37:21.009: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(202)] OnPasswordFormsRendered called
 11-15 11:37:21.009: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getSavePassword false
 11-15 11:37:21.009: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:aw_password_handler_delegate_impl.cc(203)] IsSavePasswordEnabled ret is 
 11-15 11:37:21.009: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(204)] OnPasswordFormsRendered IsEnabledSavePassword is false
 11-15 11:37:21.029: I/Ads(20419): Ad finished loading.
 11-15 11:37:21.039: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(202)] OnPasswordFormsRendered called
 11-15 11:37:21.039: D/AwPasswordHandler(20419): getSavePassword false
 11-15 11:37:21.039: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:aw_password_handler_delegate_impl.cc(203)] IsSavePasswordEnabled ret is 
 11-15 11:37:21.039: W/chromium(20419): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(204)] OnPasswordFormsRendered IsEnabledSavePassword is false
 11-15 11:37:21.359: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 64
 11-15 11:37:21.369: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 70
 11-15 11:37:21.369: E/IMGSRV(20419): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 166
 11-15 11:37:21.379: I/chromium(20419): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
 11-15 11:37:27.649: I/dalvikvm(20419): Total arena pages for JIT: 22
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant log and code? It's not clear from your question what you did to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: use Log.i(key, value) to check if you are actually getting any response back from the server. Use it where you are getting your API response from Async call. 
If you are still getting your values, then check if your adpaters are getting the actual value, whether you called them or not and subsequent viewHolder as well.

Comment: You are tring to parse value "success" from response but you are getting  this as response {"error":true,"result":"Categories not found"}, and hence the error

Comment: @sunilsunny so what can i do to resolve it?

Comment: @AnanyaSrivastav handle that case if any error returns stop the thread

Comment: Find why you are getting this response ..I think you are calling this link  http://www.orioninfosolutions.com/emoji/get_all_categories.php   .Check it's response.Also if you are getting error show that to the user and dismiss the dialog

Comment: yes @sunilsunny i am using that link

Comment: It's always giving error response.You have to handle it.Check the php side for the reason of this error

Comment: @sunilsunny can you tell me from where do you specified that link?

Comment: @AnanyaSrivastav I didn't get you ,what link ? You mean this one http://www.orioninfosolutions.com/emoji/get_all_categories.php  it's printed in your logcat.

Comment: @sunilsunny can you tell me any short trick to find where this link is placed in project files as this is a huge project and i can;t find where i placed it, thanks for helping this newbie!! And one nore request to put your way as answer to be accepted by me. :D

Comment: The easiest way will be press 'ctrl+shift+f' if you are using Studio and paste the link press find..But finding the link will not help you I guess.Find the person who did the php side..

Comment: thanks for help, please put your way as a answer @sunilsunny

Comment: @AnanyaSrivastav Here I have put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to handle the error response.You have already handled the exception that is why the app is not crashing.Findout where you are catching this exception in your case `org.json.JSONException: No value for success` Show the user some error message and dismiss the loader.

Secondly find out why you are getting error response .You are getting this response when you call your server side `{"error":true,"result":"Categories not found"}`. In your case I think it's related to the the PHP side.

Answer (score 3):

found in above logcat
 =====json returned---------{"error":true,"result":"Categories not found"}

Comment: @AnanyaSrivastav  you get "error" as message  replace "success" as "error" in your code

Comment: @RavinaBhavsar That is not the right way to handle the error.Replacing "error" with "sucess" will not give any data.The continuous loader is because op is not dismissing the loader on error response.

Comment: @sunilsunny I found that org.json.JSONException: No value for success

Comment: You're right on the cause, wrong on how to fix it.  The problem is that his webservice is returning an error.   THe problem isn't that he's looking for the wrong key, the problem is either that he fed bad data to his webservice or that the webservice can fail under certain conditions.  In the first case he needs to fix his problem, in the second he needs to display an error message to his user.

Comment: @RavinaBhavsar Yes you are right about it.But not the right suggestion to fix it.